# C# Linq Contains statement

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I wrote my own object Tag and I would like to to contains if the .Value is found (I want to simulate WHERE IN like in SQL)

```
public static List<Question> GetQuestionsIdsWithTags(List<Tag> tags)
        {
    IEnumerable<Question> res = from t in dataClasses.tags
                                    join
                                    qt in dataClasses.question_to_tags on t.id equals qt.tag_id
                                    join q in dataClasses.questions on qt.question_id equals q.id
                                    where tags.Contains<Tag>(new Tag(t.name))
                                    select new Question(q.text) { };
```

problem is, if the Contains is in the query, I get

```
The member 'Core.Literal.Value' has no supported translation to SQL.
```

Where Literal is the base of Tag.

What can I do?

Comment: You should add a tag for the ORM framework you use.

Comment: Your code isn't going to work anyway. How can `tags` contain a new instance of the tag object?

Comment: How ***exactly*** is `tags` declared here?

Comment: `Equals` makes sense for LINQ-to-Objects, but not to TSQL based repositories. Also, not that it matters here, but *in the general case* you should ensure that you keep `GetHashCode()` in sync with `Equals`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to do `new Tag(t.name)`, but this cannot be translated into SQL (the database server can't create new instances of your Tag class). Perhaps this would work:

```
IEnumerable<Question> res = from t in dataClasses.tags
                            join
                            qt in dataClasses.question_to_tags on t.id equals qt.tag_id
                            join q in dataClasses.questions on qt.question_id equals q.id
                            where tags.Select(x => x.name).Contains(t.name)
                            select new Question(q.text) { };
```

Answer (score 2):

if `tags` is a `List<string>`, you should find that:

```
where tags.Contains(t.Name)
```

works fine; but there are limits to what it can understand (and more importantly, write as TSQL).

Answer (score 1):

The LinQ `Contains()` statement can only be translated to SQL if it is performed by a `List` containing basic datatypes like `int` or `string`. If you need to cast your `tags` list to a List of strings or ints, then it should work.

Comment: How am i supposed to do that?

Comment: I don't think *cast* is the right word in this context, I think it may be more accurate to say it's a projection.